# custom partitioning failed for a centosVM

Tags: centos, boot, partition, lvm, virtual-machine

So I do have disk space for the vm available 40G.

and I want to custom the partitioning in the following way: using LVM with a `vol group = vg_root`

```
/ -2GB
/usr - 5GB
/var -2GB
/tmp- 1GB
/opt - 1GB
/home - 2GB
/swap - 4GB
```

When I try to proceed with this, it gives me error message that the /boot is not assigned and can't be LVM.

My question is, do we always have to provide a /boot parition and it should never be of type lvm ?

Comment: See this answer for additional context https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199586/27776

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to separate /boot partition & it is also a good practice to have swap  both out of LVM partitions.